# Thread/Task execution framework in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing

Suppose I have 5 tasks a,b,c,d and e. Tasks b c d depend on a and e depends on e, the 5 tasks consists a DAG.
[image]

Intuitively，the task b c d should run parallel. Is any open source library could achieve this easily?

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: I was reading into the DAG, only to later find out it is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, there is an open source lib: The JDK. Perfectly doable with Java on-board technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDK 1.8 introduced the CompletableFuture. It provides a fluent api for combining thread executions. (http://www.deadcoderising.com/java8-writing-asynchronous-code-with-completablefuture/)

In your example, it could be used this way :

```
CompletableFuture futurA = CompletableFuture.runAsync(A);
CompletableFuture futurB = futurA.thenRun(B);
CompletableFuture futurC = futurA.thenRun(C);
CompletableFuture futurD = futurA.thenRun(D);
CompletableFuture.allOf(futureB, futureC, futureD).thenRun(E);
```